# Prevent function getting called repeatedly in React

Tags: reactjs

when I call getEntries function, updateEntry and getEntries are getting called repeatedly which results I have multiple wrong datas in my database.
If I remove the getEntries call line, then updateEntry function gets complete and nothing triggers unexpectedly. Below are the snippets. Any help is much appreciated.

Have done function call as same as below those are working as expected i.e no unexpected repeating calls.

```
const updateEntry = (var1, var2) => {
 service.addEntry({var1}).then((response)=>{
 setHistory(response.data);
 getEntries()
));
}

const getEntries = () => {
 service.getEntries(id).then((response)=>{
 setEntries(response.data)
});
}

const fileProgress = ({
    uploadReady,
    downloadComplete,
    response,
    file
  }) => (
    <div>
      {downloadComplete && file.size < formData.maxFileSize ? (
        updateEntry(var1, var2)
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: share full component please!

Comment: When you are executing updateEntry() method

Comment: What and when is `updateEntry` being called? It seems you are updating some state in an asynchronous callback which will trigger a rerender, and if you are unconditionally calling that function again it will again update state. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: share full code

Comment: thank you for the comments, updated the code to show where updateEntry is being called